# Calculating euclidean distances between two data frame in python

Tags: python, dataframe, k-means

I am trying to write K-means clustering program, which needs euclidean distances in it. I understand how it works when the data is stored in a list, like the code below.

```
for featureset in data:
    distances = [np.linalg.norm(featureset - self.centroids[centroid]) for centroid in self.centroids]
    cluster_label = distances.index(min(distances))
```

But my dataset is very big (around 4 million rows) so using list or array is definitely not very efficient. I want to store the data in dataframe instead. I am thinking of iterating each row of `data` and do the euclidean calculation, but it doesn't seem so efficient, even if I am using `iteruples()` or `iterrows`. I am wondering if there is any more efficient way to do that.

Comment: so each data frame has a column that contains tuples of points?

Comment: If I truly get what you mean, yes. Each row contains a set of data points. @DmitryPolonskiy

Comment: @AnnaRG, please provide small (3-7 rows) reproducible sample data sets (in text/CSV format) and desired data set. [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1):

When you calculate the distance in your list comprehension, `centroid` is already the element of the list `self.centroids` so no need to subscipt it again in your norm calculation. Probably the code you provided should be changed to something like this:

```
distances = [np.linalg.norm(featureset - centroid) for centroid in self.centroids]
```

However, if you use the `np.array` for `data` storage this might be more efficient:

```
cluster_label = np.linalg.norm(self.centroids - featureset, axis=1).argmin()
```

Lets define the function which will return the centroid label for some `featureset`:

```
def get_label(featureset):
    return np.linalg.norm(self.centroids - featureset, axis=1).argmin()
```

now we can apply this function along the entire dataset:

```
labels = np.apply_along_axis(get_label, 1, data)
```

In case `data` is too large for processing as single `np.array` you might split it on smaller peaces, process them separately and then concatenate the results.